# Angular/directive - How to append HTML/Template when there is a new item in array?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive

I capture some photos with the camera (Phonegap) and save the image/url in an array. To display the image i would like to add something like this (image will be shown in a table):

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div class='ui-block-b'><img src=" + value + "></div>";
```

So i know i need a directive for this. My problem is to understand how to react when a new image/item will be added to the array so that i can display it.

Should i watch the array?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
angular.module('mydirectives').directive("ngImage", function ($compile) {
    return {
        template: "<div class='ui-block-b'><img src=" + {{images.image}} + "></div>",
        scope: {
        images:'='
    }
        link: function (scope, elm) {           
        scope.$watch(images, function (value) {

            // ??????
        });
        }
    };
    });
```

Comment: Add ng-repeat on the ui-block-b element?

Comment: I think a directive would be better in case of different ui-block elements (ui-block-a, ui-block-b)...what do you think? And i have the possibility to add further "html" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need a directive?  You can just do it with built in directives:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in images" class="ui-block-b"><img data-ng-src="item.image"></div>
```

ngRepeat watches images.  You just need to images.push({image: 'newUrl', imageType: 'A'}).   In addition, if you're just conditionally adding classes then you can just do something like:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in images" data-ng-class="{'ui-block-b': item.imageType == 'B', 'ui-block-a': item.imageType == 'A'}"><img data-ng-src="item".image></div>
```

And if you still want to do it with your own directive, then what you want is to watch a collection $scope.$watchCollection which is probably a bit complex.  You can also try watching just the length property of the collection.

Comment: Noogen - thanks, this was a very good idea! But there is a mistake: img data-ng-src="item".image --> "item.image" OR? --> "{{item.image}}" ... The last one did it for me ...